# How can I extend my random survival forest survival rate prediciton past years within training dataset?

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I have trained my random survival forest model using 30 years of observed observations. I would like to predict survival rate past those thirty years. Is this possible with random survival forests? I am using the ranger package to build my RSF but I have ran into similar issues with other RSF packages.

Comment: Another approach: You are probably in the tail of the distribution whatever it might be. Use extreme value distribution theory to determine the form of the tail and then fit a AFT model to the last 10 years of data.

Comment: I know this question is old but I'd strongly advise against what you're trying to do. Extrapolating is never a good idea (even with simple regression tasks), with survival it's impossible as the predictions are made from a Kaplan-Meier estimation which is trained on finite data. I would also avoid the extreme value route which will not combine well with PH predictions